# WaitForExit with CMD option "/c"

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I've written code in VB to run a CMD command, where the output is stored to a text file. This output is then needed for the program, so the program needs to wait until the CMD command has finished before continuing. I am using

```
Dim wait As Process = Process.Start(psi)
wait.WaitForExit()
```

To make sure the process exits before the code continues, but now that I've done that, the "/c" option in the process info is no longer working. The process info is as follows:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo With {
    .FileName = "Cmd",
    .Arguments = "/c " & completedCom & " > " & oPath
}
```

I do not understand why the "/c" option would fail all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces would be an example of one problem.  Use quotes around your commands to help with that:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo With {
    .FileName = "Cmd",
    .Arguments = "/c """ & completedCom & """ > """ & oPath & """"
}
```

The preferred method of calls to process would be to directly call the exec, rather than launching a cmd.  In that case, you would have to capture the standard output asynchronously and write it to a file though.

Comment: Not sure if the quotes are off or what, but now the text file remains empty

Comment: show the rest of the code...how are you checking for errors in the app?